# Open Graph Works on Wall of Facebook and on Debuggeer but not with the like button

Tags: button, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Open Graph for example on this page:

http://www.ideeaddiocelibatoenubilato.it/addio-celibato-napoli.php

This is the code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp     /DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Addio Celibato Napoli - Idee Addio Celibato E Nubilato -</title>
<meta name="description" content="Addio Celibato Napoli - Per una serata entusiasmante!"  />
<meta name="keywords" content="Addio Celibato Napoli" />
<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.ideeaddiocelibatoenubilato.it/Grafica/FacebookOG/addio-celibato-nubilato.png' />
<meta property="og:title" content=" Test OG Titolo " />
<meta property="og:description" content=" Test OG Description" />
```

It works on Facebook Walls when i post the link of the page and takes the proper image, title and description, works on the debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ideeaddiocelibatoenubilato.it%2Faddio-celibato-napoli.php

**But it doesn't work on the Like button** when I or someone else clicks on it.In that case it takes the first image it finds on the page and the title and description of the tags, not the ones of Open Graph.

I suppose the problem is in the like button.

First I Import the functions in the body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=348639055215607";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I specify that i use a unique application ID for all the LIKE buttons that I do.

And then I put the like button somewhere with javascript because of the validation:

```
<div id="likeButtonDiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   contenuto="<fb:like href='http://www.ideeaddiocelibatoenubilato.it/addio-celibato-napoli.php' send='true' layout='button_count' width='100' show_faces='false'></fb:like>";
    }
       document.getElementById('likeButtonDiv').innerHTML=contenuto;
  </script>
```

This is the SAME procedure I used for another website, tendinosirotulea.it/webmaster.php, and it works fine there.